# How can I insert custom html code inside a div dynamically?

Tags: hooks, actions

I have a class that generates some html code for me, namely the `output_tooltip` method:

```
class Tooltips_Handler {

    private $tooltip;

    public function __construct( Tooltip_Base $tooltip ) {
        $this->tooltip = $tooltip;
        add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'output_tooltip'));
    }

    public function output_tooltip() {
        echo $this->tooltip->get_html();
    }
}
```

This works for inserting the html inside the header. But I will need this to insert HTML into different sections (a section is a container div in which I insert the code, either targeted by an id `#` or class `.`) throughout my theme **and there aren't hooks for everything.**

So I'm looking to create an array that would allow me to define a `spot-to-insert` and `what-to-insert`, like this:

```
$tooltips = [
    '#instagram_widget'             => new Tooltips_Handler [..]->output_tooltip(),
    '.featured-section-audio-post'  => new Tooltips_Handler [..]->output_tooltip()
];

foreach( $tooltips as $the_location => $the_html ) {
    insert_into_section($the_location, $the_html);
}
```

This will loop through the array, generate my HTML and then insert it.

Unfortunately, I can't find a proper way to do this except loading all of the HTML and inserting it via JS, which feels clunky.

Comment: If you don't have control over the HTML (if you do, just add hooks) then JS seems like the least clunky option by _far_. If you're talking about HTML anywhere in the theme, then you'd have to capture the entire first render of the page, parse it ([not fun](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)), insert the HTML, then re-render the page with the new HTML. Just use JS.

Comment: yup, parsing html with php is not fun.  regex is just not going to be a replacement for js. i tried the js method once it was pretty tough actually. i sort of had it working but ended up not using it.